# Paypal PHP REST API

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm creating a Paypal checkout with PHP and this is the code so far:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        $clientId = "clientID";
        $secret = "secret";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
        else
        {
                $json = json_decode($result);
                    //print_r($json->access_token);
                    if ($_POST['creditcard'] == 'paypal') {
                        $data = '{
                            "intent":"sale",
                            "redirect_urls":{
                            "return_url":"http://returnurl.com",
                            "cancel_url":"http://returnurl.com"
                            },
                            "payer":{
                            "payment_method":"paypal"
                            },
                            "transactions":[
                            {
                            "amount":{
                            "total":"' . preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $order_price) .'",
                            "currency":"' . $currency_code .'"
                            },
                            "description":"' . ucfirst($type) . ' Logo Purchase. ' . '"
                            }
                            ]
                            }';

                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                            'Content-Type:application/json',
                            "Authorization: Bearer " . $json->access_token, 
                            "Content-length: ".strlen($data))
                            );
                            print_r($data);
                            $result = curl_exec($ch);

                            if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
                            else {
                                $json_output = json_decode($result);
                                print_r($result);

                                if(isset($json_output->{'links'}[2]->{'href'}))
                                    $_SESSION['execute_url'] = $json_output->{'links'}[2]->{'href'};
                                if(isset($json_output->{'links'}[1]->{'href'}))
                                    header('Location:' .$json_output->{'links'}[1]->{'href'} );
                            }

                    }

                }

        curl_close($ch);
```

I checkout with my test account and I am redirected to the redirect URL.  So I'm assuming everything is working fine.  Now the next part is what I can't figure out.  I'm trying to execute the payment here.

Do I use the payment URL that I received from my previous code above?

I tried doing this:

```
                            $data = '{ "payer_id" : "' .$_GET['PayerID'] . '" }';
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $stored_execute_url;
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                            'Content-Type:application/json',
                            "Authorization: Bearer " . $_GET['token'], 
                            "Content-length: ".strlen($data))
                            );
                            print_r($data);
                            $result = curl_exec($ch);

                            if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
```

All I'm getting is the "Error: No response."

I've been following this link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/ and I was able to get by until the last part.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was using the Token that was given in the return URL from PayPal.  I tried using the original Token and the purchase went through. Is there a purpose for the token when paypal returns to your site?

Answer (score 0):

The access token returned in the call to the OAuth2 endpoint identifies the caller and privileges (which api calls you can make).  This is required for any of the api calls (REST) to create payments, execute, refunds etc.  Some calls require more privileges than others, i.e. you need to have requested more information or provided more credentials when createing the access token.

The token returned in the URL identifies the payment, this is so that when a user is redirected back to your site, you have a way to identify which payment has been redirected back to your site and identify the proper information, i.e. execute the correct payment.

Answer (score 0):

"Authorization: Bearer " . $_GET['token'], replace this token by the previous token by storing that into session "Authorization: Bearer " . $json->access_token, this one